# Fbx file 4kb size?

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

i just downloaded Blender and i want to export a object with animation applied. I chose .fbx and go to export it. Then, I can see the export product but when open it with simple viewer as 3D Viewer it's just empty, nothing is showing. Something tricky that I found is that all of my tries are 4kb in size.
In the Hierarchy i shift selected all of the stuff. If someone can help me it would be very helpful.

[image: export settings][image]

Comment: Hard to tell without the source file / blend file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.